# Are spectrometer results affected by relativistic effects?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-spectrometry

If you throw 2 same particles into mass-spectrometer, 1 relativisticly slow and 1 relativisticly fast, would you get same result?

Comment: How would your spectrometer work with two very different velocities? You can not just "trough" the two in the same spectrometer.

Comment: You mean would the increased relativistic mass cause the particle to be deflected differently?

Comment: @JohnRennie yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a synchrotron increases the energy of electrons moving near the speed of light, the strength of the magnetic field must be increased to compensate for the relativistic increase in mass. So yes, a mass spectrometer would also notice such a change in mass.